# MariaDB 10.1 Truncate table cascade syntax error

Tags: mariadb

When i try to execute the following sql statemant MariaDB give an error:
SQL: TRUNCATE $table CASCADE;

`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASCADE' at line 1 (SQL: TRUNCATE wortmann_products CASCADE;)`

is cascade removed in MariaDB or is there something wrong whit the sql statement?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/truncate-table.html I don't see here the keyword `CASCADE` are you sure it was supported by mysql at all?

Comment: cascade is used to delete or update associated records where a dependency is found sometimes used when deleting a child record when in a parent child heirarchy and the parent record is deleted, this helps maintain referential integrity - it usually cascades deletes in this regard. - are you simply trying to truncate 1 table here?

Comment: I try to truncate a table and also delete all associated records in other tables.

Comment: then you need to cascade deletes not truncate

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to cascade out deletes and updates then the definition has to be stored when the table is created or altered, and will apply to the keys (or FK's in associated tables) allowing child records to be deleted in associated table when parent record is deleted. There are plenty of resources on this, I have listed one here:  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/the-mariadb-library/foreign-keys/ - Taken from this resource is the example below:

```
 CREATE TABLE author (
     id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
     name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
 ) ENGINE = InnoDB;

 CREATE TABLE book (
     id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
     title VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
     author_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT `fk_book_author`
        FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES author (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT
 ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: And keep in mind that `TRUNCATE` ignores `ON DELETE CASCADE`; you must use the `DELETE` statement.